# Инструменты для код-ревью веб-проектов

Tags: инспекция-кода, инструменты-разработчика

Какими инструментами вы сами пользуетесь и/или про какие знаете, что они могут быть полезны для:

- приведения кода к читаемому виду (инструменты типа плагинов [SqlBeautifier](https://github.com/zsong/SqlBeautifier), [CodeFormatter](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter) для Sublime Text 2/3)
- поиска в веб-проекте неиспользуемых переменных, блоков кода, файлов...
- проверки кода на валидность, соответствие стандартам
- поиска дублирующегося кода
- *и т.п.*

К примеру, есть огромный унаследованный проект, в котором - судя по всему - полно мусора, который оформлен чёрт знает как. Хочется автоматизировать часть рутинных задач.

Comment: [PHPCI](https://www.phptesting.org/) + соответствующие утилитоплагины: phpmd, phpcs, phpcsfixer, lint, phpcpd, pdepend - все это умеет "из коробки"

Comment: PHPCI это как из мухи по воробьям, если нужно обычное code review, достаточно phing`а с означенными тулзами.

Если нужно полноценное CI, то PHPCI еще немного не дорос, ибо не умеет например деплоить из коробки. Jenkins  сейчас умеет все тоже самое

Comment: @donkey, мне удобно сидеть на этом стеке.